# Internal fan controller

Tags: cooling, fan-controller

I'm looking for internal fan controller which will meet my requirements:

- internal (I want to put it inside my case)
- set fan speeds based on GPU & CPU temperature
- it has to control at least **four 3-pin fans**
- price: **under 50$**

My proposition:
[NZXT GRID+V2](https://www.nzxt.com/products/GRID-Plus-v2)

Is there any good alternative for NZXT GRID+V2 ? Maybe you can suggest some other cheaper/better solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After no response I bought **NZXT GRID+V2** and I can easily recommend this hardware to anyone looking for internal fan controller with many features.

### **Setup:**

I installed it in Phanteks Enthoo Evolv ITX with one 200 mm intake fan and three 140 mm exaust fans.

[image: setup1]
[image: setup2]

It is connected to motherboard through USB connector and to PSU (12V) with Molex 4-Pin connector.

### **CAM Software:**

This is dedicated software for this fan controller which allows not only controling fans but also gives many options of monitoring hardware.

- **fan controller** (it allows to customize curve of each fan speed according to GPU or CPU temprature)

[image: fancontroller]

- **system monitor** (CPU,GPU,RAM,HDD,SSD,MOBO,NET)

[image: monitor1] 
[image: monitor2]

- **FPS overlay** (allow to put and customize overlay with FPS, CPU temprature and load, GPU temprature and load and other visible on screen)

[image: overlay1]
[image: overlay2]

**Final conclusion:**

I paid for NZXT GRID+ V2 **$40** and I think it's absolutly worth this price. **It is not only fan controller** it is also really good system monitor and fps overlay. I can recommend it to anyone looking for internal fan controller.